# VBA Excel: Replacing all sheets .CodeName value with .Name value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change all sheets' `.codename` value in VBA to their corresponding `.name` values.
I am trying the below mentioned code but its not working. Kindly advise

```
Dim Ws As Variant
For k = 1 To 37
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Ws(k)).CodeName = Ws(k).Name
Next k
```

Comment: From the VBA help:

"You cannot programmatically change this property at run time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to head onto *Macro Security*, on my version of Excel this can be found on the Developer tab.
Then tick the box that says "*Trust access to the VBA project object model*".
The following code should then allow you to achieve what you want:

```
Sub test()
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.CodeName).Name = ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but you'll have to press ok a lot of times for a lot of sheets.

Comment: The MsgBox is obviously just to show you that the codename has changed and was just for testing.

Comment: Also bear in mind that not all valid tab names are valid codenames.